# Create section and index on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting

I have NSMutableArray which contains both name and photo's string of a contact list.

```
[contactArray addObject:[[Contact alloc]initWithName:cName andPhoto:cPhoto]];
```

I want to make a contact list, so I sorted that array based on name like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
      [contactArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Now I want to group it to sections with initial of only name in my array and index from # to Z to directly guide me to exact section. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSDictionary as the data source, the keys of the NSDictionary should be # to Z, and the object for each key is an array of contacts.

Then the numberOfSections should be the number of keys in the dictionary,
And the numberOfRowsInSection should be the number of items of the array

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? I'm newbie in Xcode and objective-C. I have no idea how to do that. Thanks in advance, @Shadowfiend